# javascript error when accessing flash redirect attribute (thymeleaf, springmvc)

Tags: javascript, java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm currently stuck with the following problem with SpringMVC, Thymeleaf and Javascript.

1) Server-Side: Under some circumstances I add a flash redirect attribute in my controller before redirecting to a certain page.

```
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("myCondition", true);
```

2) Client-Side: In case that attribute exists, I want my javascript function to execute additional code.

```
window.onload = function() {
    ...
    if([[${myCondition}]]) {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This works fine after the redirect, but on first enter the redirect attribute does simply not exist, which results in the following javascript code being rendered:

```
    window.onload = function() {
    if() {
        //do something
    }
}
```

This code is not valid and therefore produces a javascript error. 
I'm not sure how to check with javascript if the redirect attribute exists?

Answer (score 1):

can you try the following code and let me know if this works for you
declare a variable mycondition

```
var mycondition = [[${myCondition}]];

if(mycondition) {
   //do something
}
```

Hope this helps